# Do I have to merge gh-pages to master in order to publish a repository with a dist folder?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I had problems publishing my project, which uses a dist folder as the root directory.
I ran: `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`on the command line. That created a new `gh-pages` branch. Should I now create a pull request and merge the `gh-pages` branch into `master`? And/or which branch should I pick as a source for GitHub Pages?

Comment: What makes you think that you should you PR gh-pages into master? They don't share history, and the two branches contain totally different things. If you've pushed the build outputs to the gh-pages branch, pick that branch as the source for GH Pages.

Comment: Ok thanks :) So I will pick the gh-pages as the source for gitHub pages